# Dúvida concatenação de colunas

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, script, firebird

O código abaixo, retorna uma soma por classificação.
Algo como:
Serviços = tipo 1
Materiais = tipo 2

o resultado esperado é que exista apenas uma linha, e que nessa Linha eu tenha o valor de cada tipo por coluna .

```
select distinct
C.COD,
c.paciente,
--C.CON || '-' || T.NOME Convenio ,
C.TIPO_CTA,
l.tipo,
sum (L.VALOR_C) over(partition by (L.TIPO) ) total
from FCCTAEXT C
LEFT join FCLANEXT L on C.ID = L.ID_FCCTAEXT
left join TBCONVEN T on (T.COD = C.CON)
left join RECADATE E on E.REG = C.REG_ATE
where
c.reg_ate = 1654385 and
C.IND_EMI = 'T'
  and ((C.ANOPRO = 2021
  and C.MESPRO = 7))
  and C.TIPO_CTA = 'E'
  and C.CON = 12
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma alternativa ao subselect para atender esse caso ?

Comment: isso é um pivot... com sql é complicado, mas você pode gerar a query dinamicamente ou fazer isso apenas na exibição do resultado

Answer (score -1):

O Firebird não tem suporte a pivot table, porem se precisa destes dados em tela, da para utilizar o cxGrid da paleta devExpress mais atualizada, ela tem suporte a pivot table ok

outra saida, seria tratar os dados retornados da sua select em algo na memória, como um ClientDataSet por exemplo, localizando os registros existentes e agregando valores a eles, e só no final exportando estes dados para onde você precisa

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.